# Flask problems handling a request with URLencoded parameters

Tags: python, flask, webargs

I'm having a weird problem; I'm running Flask and I have an API function to cancel memberships. The URL also contains a parameter to set a reason for cancelation. this is a short text, and it can contain extended characters, so the string is URLencoded by the calling party.

In certain cases however, Flask returns a 400 error, before it even reaches my own processing code. For example, the following URL:

```
curl -X "DELETE" "http://localhost:5000/contracts/C9ABA4AA-834E-4711-91A8-F21057DF693B?date=2015-8-1&canceldate=2015-6-27&booktoday=true&overrideEnddate=true&cancelreason=traslado+a+m%C3%A1s+de+15+km&correctionreason="
```

Gives me a 400 error: *The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.* although it seems to be a perfectly valid URL.
When I trap the error the underlying error data is:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\\xe1' in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I found out that all is well when I remove the encoded extended character **á**  (%C3%A1) from the URL string.

I can also solve it by adding this workaround I found elsewhere to my app.**init**()

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

I understood that this statement forces the Python interpreter to use UTF-8 by default to decode bytestrings, instead of ASCII.
This gives me a solution to my problem, but it feels overly complicated and unnessecary.

So, the real question is, what am I missing here? Is there a setting within Flask that I don't know about that solves this, or can it really be the case that Flask can't handle specific URL encoded strings?
I would expect Flask to be able to handle URL encoded parameters by itself, without a workaround in non-library code...

I have no traceback, because Flask will trap it and handle it as an HTTP error and return a 400 HTTP status code.

**EDIT**:
The origin of the exception is in this part of the Flask code (site-packages\flask\app.py):

```
def full_dispatch_request(self):
    """Dispatches the request and on top of that performs request
    pre and postprocessing as well as HTTP exception catching and
    error handling.

    .. versionadded:: 0.7
"""
self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
try:
    request_started.send(self)
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
    if rv is None:
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
except Exception as e:
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
response = self.make_response(rv)
response = self.process_response(response)
request_finished.send(self, response=response)
return response
```

The code skips to the except: and returns a 400 error.

Thanks for any pointers you can give me.

Comment: No tracebacks are available even when using the Flask debug server ?

Comment: @Ketouem, yes there is a traceback, but only when I put a breakpoint in the code. Flask handles the "faulty" querystring gracefully and instead returns an http error 400.

Comment: Could you include the code of faulty view with the question ?

Comment: @Ketouem; there's no view, it returns JSON, but it already fails on the request, it doesn't even reach my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the solution; And it seems I left out some essential information in my question that was needed to resolve the issue.

We tried to duplicate the problem in a very simple single-page Flask app, so I could put it up here on StackOverflow as an example. However, the simple Flask testpage worked fine, so we went to look for the differences.

What I totally forgot, and we noticed just then, was that we use the [webargs](https://github.com/sloria/webargs) library to parse http parameters.

The parameters were parsed as strings, and there also is a type unicode available in webargs. Changing the type to unicode solved the problem.

```
@api.route('/contracts/<ppl_mshp_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
@use_args({'date': Arg(type_=str, validate=is_date, required=False),
           'canceldate': Arg(type_=str, validate=is_date, required=False),
           'cancelreason': Arg(type_=unicode, required=False, default=u""),
           'correction': Arg(type_=float, required=False),
           'correctionreason': Arg(type_=unicode, required=False, default=u""),
           'restitution': Arg(type_=bool, required=False, default=False),
           'booktoday': Arg(type_=bool, required=False, default=False),
           'overrideEnddate': Arg(type_=bool, required=False, default=False),
           })
def cancel_contract(args, ppl_mshp_id):
...
```

Thank you @ketouem for your time and trouble, and sorry for being incomplete in my question.